# Another Return from Initializer without initializing all stored properties error

Tags: swift

Why am I getting a `"Return from Initializer without initializing all stored properties"` even though I already initialized everything?

In this simple case everything in struct Foo is initialized, both explicitly and in the `Foo.init()` routine. So why does the code fail on the close of the `Bar.init()` routine?

```
struct Foo {
    var x: Double = 0.0
    var y: Double = 0.0
    var z: Double = 0.0

    init() {
        x = 0.0
        y = 0.0
        z = 0.0
    }
}

struct Bar {
    var i: Int = 0
    var f: Foo

    init (i: Int) {
        self.i = i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Bar` you have `var f: Foo`, which requires that you set a value for it, but your `init` only sets `i`. You must either give it a default value or set it in your `init` method.

Comment: Ah! I just need to change "var f: Foo" into "var f = Foo()". Thanks